# Kotlin error while referencing Activity from Inner Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

I have an AsyncTask as an inner class inside my Activity written in Kotlin. Now, I tried to access the Activity from my AsyncTask's onPostExecute using `this@MyActivity` but Android Studio reports it as Unresolved Reference error. But this is the most common method suggested online for referencing the OuterClass from an InnerClass. The code is as follows:

```
class MyActivity : AbstractAppPauseActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}

class MyTask(private var mContext: Context?, val pbMigrating: ProgressBar) :AsyncTask<Void, Int, Void>() {


    private var size: Long = 0

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        ...

    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
        ...
        return null
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        pbMigrating.progress = values[0] as Int

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        this@MyActivity //<- Cannot Resolve error here 
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to make class as inner

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
    } inner class MyTask(private var mContext: Context?, val pbMigrating: ProgressBar) : AsyncTask<Void, Int, Void>() {

        private var size: Long = 0

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
            return null
        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
            pbMigrating.progress = values[0] as Int
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            this@MyActivity //<- Cannot Resolve error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was trying out Kotlin for the first time so did not know about this.

Answer (score 2):

The class MyTask must be defined as an inner class:

```
inner class MyTask(
    private var mContext: Context?,
    val pbMigrating: ProgressBar
) : AsyncTask<Void, Int, Void>()
{
    ...
}
```